# Obtain Thévenin equivalent with two voltage sources in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, thevenin

[image]

I want to get the Thévenin equivalent of the circuit above.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHgGLt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I applied source transformation, and now I have two voltage sources in parallel, but I don't know how to proceed. The final result should be something like this:

[image]

Someone can explain me this part of the resolution?

Comment: The final result looks right to me. First convert the cosine source and its series resistance into Norton. You can then add that to the parallel current source on the left and combine the two resulting parallel resistances (2k and 3k)=1.2k. If you multiply that 1.2k times the summed current sources you will get the left side of the final result. And the Norton to Thevenin of the right side is obvious. So the final result looks good to me.

Comment: Thevenin only applies to linear circuits.

Comment: Felipe, your *source transformation* as shown in the **CircuitLab** schematic is incorrect...as shown, V2 is the *only* active source (V1, R1 are redundant). The diode's cathode should see two sources of equal strength, not V2 dominating V1.

Answer (score 1):

The left part of your transformation is incorrect.
The Thévenin resistance given by the left side is 3//2 = 1.2 kΩ.

V1 should be in series with the 2 kΩ resistance, and V2 in series with the 3 kΩ resistance.

So then
$$20 - 5kI-30 \sin(\omega t)=0$$
$$4\ \mathrm{mA} -6\sin(\omega t)\ \mathrm{mA}=I$$
$$20\ \mathrm{V}-2\ \mathrm{k \Omega}(4\ \mathrm{mA} -6\sin(\omega t)\ \mathrm{mA})=20-8+12\sin(\omega t)=12+12\sin(\omega t)$$